# Doctrine: ODM vs. ORM

Tags: mongodb, orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm, nosql

I consider using ODM/ORM/mixing ODM and ORM entities in my new Doctrine 2.0 project. When should I use ORM (MySQL InnoDB) and when ODM (MongoDB)? Should I mix it in one project?

Pseudo structure of my app (Google Reader like):

- user { id, login, password, email }
- channel { id, url }
- entry { id, channelId, title, body, date }
- entryValue { entryId, userId, value }
- userFriend { user1Id, user2Id }

Most popular functions:

- getValuesOfNewsByUsers(newsId, [userIdArray])
- getEntriesByUserWithMinValue(userId, minValue)
- areFriends(user1, user2)
- getEntryValues(userId, [entryIdArray])

I should be prepared for billions of rows in *entry* and *entryValue* tables.

Comment: I think this question is not realy answer-able. There are many posts on SO that highlight the differences and when to use what. For example http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=use+cases+nosql holds many good answers (try sorting by "votes")